# Manually shutdown mongod.exe won't fire an error using node-mongodb-native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

this is my first post on here.

I am learning Node and Mongodb. I have installed the node-mongodb-native driver and found some unexpected things.

My script is below, based on [the official tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html).

```
var test;  //short cut for later use

require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
    if (err) {return console.log("some error",err);}

    console.log("database connected");

    test = db.collection('test');
    test.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        if (err) {console.log("some error");} 
        else {console.log("still connected");}
    });

});

var rep = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        test.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            if (err) {console.log("some error: " + err);} 
            else {console.log("still connected");}
        });           
        rep(); 
    }, 2000);
}   

rep();
```

So every after 2 seconds, the console.log outputs "still connected", this is expected.

If the mongod.exe window is shutdown (to simulate a loss of connection to the database), I expect to see "some error" in the console.log. However, no error message is logged.

When the mongod.exe is restarted (to simulate a reconnection), the console.log outputs **many** streams of "still connected"

I have not been able to find the answer from the manual or other online sources. So 2 questions from me:

1) What is the current best practice to detect sudden mongodb disconnection apart from on.('close') and should there be an error being emitted using the find() query when such disconnection happens?

2) Upon reconnection, the console.log outputs many lines of the same messages as if they have been queued during the disconnection and now being logged at once. Is this normal? I can think of a real life issue: instead of find(), an admin maybe using insert() to add some data. The database connection is disrupted but there is no error message, so the admin maybe doing many insert() and still see no result. Then upon reconnection, a swarm of insert() queries inundates the database?

Please point at my ignorance...

Comment: What's wrong with using the `close` event?